# How to treat the verb after 'work' when treating 'work' as a plural

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I want to refer to several studies (which I call it work). It is plural. I am not sure whether I should use `s` with the verb after it or not?

```
Previous work shows that ..
```

OR

```
Previous work show that ..
```

Comment: Previous work in several studies shows A, B and C. Work is always singular, except works of art and construction works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context work is not countable, so your first example is correct. If you wanted to say "Previous papers..." then "paper" is countable and you should use the plural verb "show".

Comment: Just so.  "Previous work" is an uncountable singular.  Countably singular examples include "a previous work" and "the previous work".  Countably plural would be "previous works".